# Use SHGetKnownFolderPath() instead of ApplicationData class to get LocalAppData path

Tags: winapi, uwp, desktop-bridge

In an desktop-bridge app, I want to find the LocalAppData (or LocalCache) folder of that specific package. I can get the LocalCache folder path with [ApplicationData class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.applicationdata):

```
using Windows.Storage;
string appData = ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder.Path;
```

Alternatively, if I use [SHGetKnownFolderPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762188(v=vs.85).aspx) function I can also get that same path:

```
wchar_t* appData;
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_LocalAppData, KF_FLAG_FORCE_APP_DATA_REDIRECTION, NULL, &appData);
```

So my question: Is it appropriate to use `SHGetKnownFolderPath()` instead of ApplicationData class? Both give same path in UWP environment. Is there any drawback/cons to use the first one?

Comment: I won't be surprised if first approach actually involved a nested call to `SHGetKnownFolderPath` with some extra overhead but `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is not available for UWP environment at all. Not sure whether such a restriction apply to the desktop-bridge app.

Comment: One drawback of calling `SHGetKnownFolderPath` is, that you are responsible for memory management. And since you asked for *any* drawbacks, VTT is correct in pointing out, that this API call isn't available to UWP applications. Even if this code is in a desktop application currently, it just makes it harder to move it into a Windows Runtime Component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call any methods before you convert your desktop app to UWP app.
Once you converted it successfully, after that, if you want to extend it, for example: [Extend your desktop application with modern UWP components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-extend), then, you would have to use UWP APIs.